# How to show a table with 10+ columns?

Tags: android, tableview, material-design, user-experience

since the android screen is small to show a table with 10+ columns so, I was wondering what is the best approach to show this kind of table according to material design guidlines

The data from website that should be shown in android looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should ask that over on https://ux.stackexchange.com ?